# Could taking pictures of a [candle] flame damage my camera?

Tags: equipment-damage, candlelight

I'm slightly inspired by the picture in [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20927/what-is-a-point-of-interest-in-a-photograph-and-where-is-it-lacking-in-this-cand) involving candle flames.

I'm interested in taking similar pictures of candle flames and fire more generally, but I worry that it might cause damage to either the optics or the sensor. Is this a legitimate worry?

In case the answer would vary based on the quality of my equipment, I currently have a Canon 550D, the standard 18-55mm kit lens and a Tamron 70-300mm (all fairly low-level stuff, I know).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless you get so close to the flame that you burn or get soot on the front lens element, photographing candles will not damage your camera.

Assuming your 70-300 lens has the same 1:2 macro setting as mine, this is probably your best option; I have taken some good shots of igniting matches with that lens.

Comment: Correct. But on the same line of thought: do be careful about lasers. Those _can_ damage your sensor.

Comment: @Roflo What about eyes when you look through view finder. Need to be careful when shooting a bright Sun as well.

Comment: Right @kantu, that's worth mentioning too.