# Is there a way to display golden ratio and the rule of thirds on a Canon DSLR?

Tags: canon, composition, rule-of-thirds, golden-ratio

There is not much talk about the Golden Ratio in the web, and all of them are almost the same. I have a Canon 1200D, and I was mostly interested to learn more about this, and specifically, to be able to see the golden ratio curve on my Canon DSLR's monitor. I read somewhere that I should install a plug-in, but I did not understand the procedure, or the plugin. Is there another  method?

Comment: We actually have a lot about the Golden Ratio here on this site. See [this for example](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8965/what-is-the-golden-ratio-and-why-is-it-better-than-the-rule-of-thirds/9312#9312).

Comment: you could try [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00L3EHAE6) plus [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00EPQSQ1A)

Comment: So you mean that I stick the protector and draw the curve with the pencil ?

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** My answer below suggests using Magic Lantern, but at the time of this writing that's not possible because the 1200D isn't among the models supported by Magic Lantern. There's a list of supported models on the [main ML web page](http://www.magiclantern.fm) -- perhaps the 1200D will be listed there someday.

---

> Is there a way to display golden ration together with rule of thirds on Canon?

**No,** the composition marks built into your camera don't include a golden ratio spiral or rectangle.

**However,** as you mention, there is software that you can install on your camera that makes it possible to display whatever guide lines you like. [Magic Lantern](http://www.magiclantern.fm) is the tool you need to install on your camera, and then there's also a bit of work that you need to do in order to create the custom "crop marks" file that you want. Here are two web pages that describe the process, after you've installed Magic Lantern:

- [Custom Crop Marks](http://magiclantern.wikia.com/wiki/Cropmarks) from the Magic Lantern Firmware Wiki
- [Custom Crop Marks (Black or White)](http://jamiebrightmore.com/photography/magic-lantern-custom-crop-marks-black-white/) from Jamie Brightmore's blog

Installing Magic Lantern itself is pretty straightforward -- it's largely a matter of copying it onto a memory card and putting the card in your camera. [Installation instructions](http://wiki.magiclantern.fm/install) are available on the Magic Lantern web site.

Comment: There's no ML for the 1200D yet, though.

Comment: Thank you so much , so , what do I do then ? Does 1100 D go for me as well ?

Comment: the 1100 D build fails

Comment: @Farzad64 Sorry to lead you astray -- I didn't notice that the 1200D isn't supported yet. I'll leave the answer here with a note for other readers who might have the same question but other camera models. For you, I'm afraid there aren't a lot of options besides hoping someone will port Magic Lantern to the 1200D -- the built-in firmware doesn't support what you're asking for.

Comment: thank you so much Caleb, I wish there would be a solution , but one curiosity , is there too much difference between 1100 D and 1200 D ?

Comment: @Farzad64 It's an open source project supported by a community of volunteer developers, and they may not have access to a 1200D (or motivation) to do the port.