# What is it called

Tags: terminology

When the point starts in the middle and goes in ever expanding circles till it ends up on the outside of the lens area. It ends up looking like the inside of a seashell?

Comment: Do you mean a logarithmic spiral?

Comment: Please give an example of what you're talking about.

Comment: Do you mean a [Fibonacci Spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Fibonacci_spiral.svg)?

Comment: Or possibly a [Fresnel Lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Flat_flexible_plastic_sheet_lens.JPG)?

Comment: Related: [How to use the Fibonacci spiral to create better photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/73727/15871)

Comment: @PeterPawlicki - I added a couple of example photos of a **guess** of what you mean, to (hopefully) improve your question and assist you in getting better answers. If it was an error to do that please edit your question to remove the photos and kindly provide an image or improve upon your description. Thanks for asking, apologies if the example is incorrect.

Comment: @Rob I'm not seeing anything added...

Comment: @MichaelClark - I added two photos. The system says: "Thanks for your edit!
This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed. " - It's odd that **you** can't see anything. If I come back in a couple of hours and there's nothing I'll retry. I can't revert because it doesn't show up in the 'Edited List' (even for  me, the *last* ? Editor) showing scottbb as the last editor. -- Broken? -- Not sure what's up. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: @MichaelClark - Clicking the PR link shows "Philip Kendall reviewed this 6 hours ago: Reject
This is guessing what the author meant, we need the author to clarify" - I added two relevant 'Golden Ratio' photos, and the answer is making the same guess - not sure what other guess could be made. Phillip's 14K rep so I guess he can reject on his own but it didn't 'go through' and both shows (to me) waiting for review and clicking the PR link rejected. Here's the Link: https://photo.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/6121 .

Comment: @Rob no, the system isn't broken. Your edit is in the Suggested Edits review queue at the moment. It needs 3 (I think) approve votes for it to go through. I have hesitated on reviewing it, because I had the same reaction Philip did. I was hoping OP would jump in an clarify the question a bit, which would make the approve/reject decision a lot easier.

Comment: @scottbb - As long as nothing is broken it's all good. I would have chosen skip over reject but each is free to choose whichever ... - It goes without saying that I made the edit with intentions of being helpful and improving the question, left a comment for Peter, etc. Not sure why MC couldn't see anything. True, the OP's opinion would be the most helpful, his ability to revert (does he have it?) would have fixed my fixing. Me being the one whom made the edit must weight out on having an opinion (or whining) and leave it the way it ends up being resolved.

Comment: @Rob understood, your intentions are not in question at all. Not trying to speak for Philip, but my hesitance comes from feeling the edit is _just_ a bit too much putting words in OP's mouth. That's only my opinion. There's a fine line in editing, between editing for grammar/formatting/spelling, etc., vs. editing for _correctness_ or voice. That's why one of the reject reasons is "Clearly conflicts with the author's intention". I haven't rejected it on those grounds, because it's not clear what OP intended. (which actually is how I voted to close the question until it is clarified).

Comment: It is not currently in the suggested edit que nor do the rejected edits show in the revision history.

Comment: If the intent was regarding a Fibonacci spiral, then this question is essentially a duplicate of [How to use the Fibonacci spiral to create better photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/73727/15871) since what it is is called is covered in the question/answers concerned with how to use it.

Comment: I've started [a chat room about the edit](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74235/rejected-edit).

Comment: @MichaelClark User inkista wrote: "This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive", so the person doesn't understand English and likes to defame people. That was the second vote and with that it was gone, so should they be.

Comment: @Rob Yeah, using the direct link in your comment above I can see it. But that's the only way to get there. Without knowledge of the exact link it is impossible to find via the normal SE interface. I'm not sure I'd go so far as to say it is destructive or spam. It seems to me it is highly probable the question was in reference to Fibonacci Spirals.

Comment: @MichaelClark - That is why I earlier questioned if something was broken, you ought to be able to see it. The rest of us seem to be able to access the info though I don't see it in the "edited yesterday" link; still showing scottbb. If it's broken for you I'll leave it up to you to file a Bug Report. Until Peter returns and chooses to clarify the question we can only guess. I'm satisfied that it's both answered and a dupe. I'm moving on to more productive use of my time as I value rep at 1¢ per point; and we've put more than our 2¢ into this.

Comment: It's not about rep. It's about creating a culture here that is welcoming and promotes the resources the site has to offer instead of continuing to run off as many potential users as possible and direct them to external resources.

Answer (score 4):

Although the question is vague, it's been posted on a photography question site, so my guess is that this is called the `golden section` or `golden ratio`. The ratio of the sum to the larger of the two quantities.

This site seems to show quite a good explanation:

> Simply put, the golden ratio is a ratio of approximately 1.618 to 1. This proportion creates a sense of harmony and balance.

Taken from: https://photographyicon.com/goldenratio/

There are some good representations of it in action, and some video links

The visual representation is often seen as this:

[image]

The golden ratio and using the closely related Fibonacci spiral is also well covered here in these questions:

[How to use the Fibonacci spiral to create better photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/73727/15871)
[What is the 'Golden Ratio' and why is it better than the 'Rule of Thirds?'](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/8965/15871)
[Subject alongside, at the intersection or inside lines in composition rules?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/29301/15871)
[What is the 'Diagonal Method' and should I use it instead of 'The Rule of Thirds?'](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/11060/15871)