# Subject out of center — what is correct term?

Tags: terminology, composition

Composition which consists of placing the topic or main subject to the side and never in center of the picture: does that technique have a name?

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure that it's just "subject off-center", with no special words. A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=subject%20off%20center) for that term returns a million results, and I don't see a common other term used, let alone a consensus for some other label.

However, in photography over the past century, it's pretty strongly related to the [rule of thirds](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/9239/1943), which is widely understood as a suggestion to compose in exactly this way, with subjects a third of the way into the frame rather then centered. (The original "rule of thirds" was about dividing lines or blocks of color in a composition, but the idea of subject placement is very strong in its modern oft-repeated incarnation. You'll see it often in the search results above, although clearly not all off-center subjects follow the strict guideline.)

The idea that the fraction ¹⁄₃ (or any other particular [ratio](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/9312/1943)) is special isn't based on anything rational, but it's generally true that centered subjects tend to be more static; using an off-center subject allows use of tension and dynamic balance in composition. (More on this under [When is it OK to place the subject in the middle of a picture?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16694/when-is-it-ok-to-place-the-subject-in-the-middle-of-a-picture))

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are referring to the Rule of Thirds which states that when composing a shot, it's better to position things along 1/3s horizontally and spread them between the two thirds vertically.

Answer (score 1):

"Dynamic."

Centred is "static."